# Why am I getting an error message in Python for using match?

Tags: python, switch-statement, match

I am receiving a syntax error in Python when I type the word Match. I even have the latest version of Python 3.11.4

```
http_status = 200

if http_status == 200 or http_status == 201:
    print("success")
elif http_status == 400:
    print("Bad request")
elif http_status == 404:
    print("Not found")
elif http_status == 500 or http_status == 501:
    print("Server Error")
else: 
    print("Unknown")

match http_status:
    case 200:
        print("success")
```

ERROR MESSAGE :

match http_status:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I checked if my syntax was correct and it is. I am not sure if the version I have doesn't accept match anymore

Comment: Are you certain the version of Python you're running is 3.11.4, and not some earlier install?  Add `print(sys.version)` to your code and see what it says.

Comment: Your code will **not** raise a SyntaxError exception in Python 3.11.4. In fact, it would only happen if your Python version is prior to 3.10 (which is when match/case was introduced)

Comment: @TomKarzes 
This is what I get for print(sys.error)
success
3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]

When I type in python3 -- version in my terminal, I get the 3.11.4

Comment: @lexi_roro I assume you meant `sys.version`, not `sys.error`. 
 So you have two different Python installs.  When you run Python interactively, you're getting 3.11.4, but when you run your Python program, you're getting 3.9.6.  That explains your problem.  How are you running your program?  You need to fix it so that it uses 3.11.4 rather than 3.9.6.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you Tom for your help! I figured out the issue. When I opened up the Visual Studio code application on its own (without using the terminal), it recommended the Python Interpreter 3.9.6. On my terminal, when I typed in "python3 --version" then typed in "code .", it opened up visual studio code and showed the option to use the interpreter for 3.11.4